# How to set a shortcut to open syntax specific settings file on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: settings, sublimetext3, shortcut

Is there a way to set a shortcut similar to the existing command below?

`{ "keys": ["super+,"], "command": "open_file", "args": {"file": "${packages}/User/Preferences.sublime-settings"} }`

But instead of opening the Preferences Settings file, I'd like to open the *Syntax Specific* settings file corresponding to the extension of the active file.

(Instead of having to go to `Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User` everytime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is called `open_file_settings`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "open_file_settings" }
```

Here's how I figured it out:

1. Open the console (ctrl+`)
2. Type `sublime.log_commands(True)`
3. Go to *Preferences* → *Settings - More* → *Syntax Specific - User*
4. You'll see:

   ```
   command: open_file_settings
   ```
5. Type `sublime.log_commands(False)`